# python converting csv

Tags: python, sql

I am converting a CSV file into a SQL query and I have this output. Could you recommend how to avoid this trouble?

My code is:

```
import csv
import unicodedata

openFile = open('region_mapping.csv', 'r')
csvFile = csv.reader(openFile)
header = next(csvFile)
headers = map((lambda x: '`'+x+'`'), header)
insert = 'INSERT INTO Table (' + ", ".join(headers) + ") VALUES "
for row in csvFile:
    values = map((lambda x: '"'+x+'"'), row)
    print (insert +"("+ ", ".join(values) +");" )
openFile.close()
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO toolbox.region ( province_name;min_order_price;region_name ) VALUES ( '��������� ����;10000;4 ���� (��������� ������)' );
```

An example of the file is:

```
province_name,min_order_price,region_name
Алтайский край,10000,4 зона (Восточная Сибирь)
```

Comment: Provide sample CSV data that reproduces the issue.  See [mcve].  Assuming Python 3, `open` probably needs an explicit encoding specified because the CSV is not in the default encoding for your system.

Comment: province_name min_order_price region_name
Алтайский край 10000 4 зона (Восточная Сибирь)

Comment: It is cyrillyc alphabet

Comment: province_name                               min_order_price region_name
Алтайский край      10000            4 зона (Восточная Сибирь)

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show your Python Version. Did you know the Code-Page the `CSV` is saved?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a correct encoding for the file prints correctly, but "prints correctly" assumes an appropriate console or IDE encoding and a font with available characters.  If using Windows, I recommend use Python 3.6 if that is an option.  It fixes problems printing to the console, but you still need a font that supports the characters being printed.

Note: You're file encoding may vary.  That is difficult to tell unless you provide a hexdump of the file content.  Since you didn't get a UnicodeDecodeError, you may have the correct encoding, but an incorrect font or stdout encoding to support Cyrillic.

```
import csv

openFile = open('region_mapping.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8')
csvFile = csv.reader(openFile)
header = next(csvFile)
headers = map((lambda x: '`'+x+'`'), header)
insert = 'INSERT INTO Table (' + ", ".join(headers) + ") VALUES "
for row in csvFile:
    values = map((lambda x: '"'+x+'"'), row)
    print (insert +"("+ ", ".join(values) +");" )
openFile.close()
```

Input:

```
province_name,min_order_price,region_name
Алтайский край,10000,4 зона (Восточная Сибирь)
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO Table (`province_name`, `min_order_price`, `region_name`) VALUES ("Алтайский край", "10000", "4 зона (Восточная Сибирь)");
```

The output doesn't match yours, so I suspect either that *isn't* the output of the displayed code, or that isn't the exact code you used.

Comment: г Москва 4000 1 зона (Москва, Северо-Запад, Центральная Россия, Поволжье )
г Санкт-Петербург 4000 1 зона (Москва, Северо-Запад,

Comment: @Jack what exactly does that mean? You'll need to provide more info (edit your question) about your environment (Python version, OS, how you are viewing the output, etc.)